# Select all columns but unix_timestamp createdate

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP/MySQL

I need to select all the columns in the table, but convert the column 'createdate', which is saved as a current_timestamp to a unix_timestamp within the query.

Comment: Great. Good luck with that. Post the answer once you've solved it so that we can all benefit from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function:

```sql
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdate) AS unix_createdate FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function built in MySQL.

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
    -> 1196440210
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
    -> 1196440219
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp